# How to correctly add a date and a time (string) in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

What is the "cleanest" way to add a date and a time string in PHP?

Albeit having read that `DateTime::add` expects a `DateInterval`, I tried

```
$date = new \DateTime('17.03.2016');
$time = new \DateTime('20:20');
$result = $date->add($time);
```

Which was no good and returned nothing to `$result`.

To make a `DateInterval` from `'20:20'`, I only found very complex solutions...

Maybe I should use timestamps?

```
$date = strtotime($datestring);
$timeObj = new \DateTime($timestring);
// quirk to only get time in seconds from string date
$time = $timeObj->format('H') * 3600 + $timeObj->format('i') * 60 + $timeObj->format('s');
$datetime = $date+$time;
$result = new \DateTime;
$result->setTimestamp($datetime);
```

In my case, this returns the desired result, with the correct timezone offset. But what do you think, is this robust? Is there a better way?

Comment: I like to use Carbon (https://carbon.nesbot.com/)

Comment: Nice one! For a bigger project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add 20 hours and 20 minutes to a `DateTime`:

```
$date = new \DateTime('17.03.2016');
$date->add($new \DateInterval('PT20H20M'));
```

You do not need to get the result of `add()`, calling `add()` on a `DateTime` object will change it. The return value of `add()` is the `DateTime` object itself so you can chain methods.

See [DateInterval::__construct](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) to see how to set the intervals.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` (and `DateTimeImmutable`) has a `modify` method which you could leverage to modify the time by adding `20 hours` and `20 minutes`.

## Updated

I've included examples for both `DateTime` and `DateTimeImmutable` as per  the comment made, you don't need to assign the outcome of `modify` to a variable because it mutates the original object. Whereas `DateTimeImmutable` creates a new instance and doesn't mutate the original object.

### DateTime

```
<?php

$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2018-10-23 00:00:00');
echo $start->modify('+20 hours +20 minutes')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// 2018-10-23 20:20:00
```

Using `DateTime`: https://3v4l.org/6eon8

### DateTimeImmutable

```
<?php

$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2018-10-23 00:00:00');
$datetime = $start->modify('+20 hours +20 minutes');

var_dump($start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
var_dump($datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

#### Output

> string(19) "2018-10-23 00:00:00"
>
> string(19) "2018-10-23 20:20:00"

Using `DateTimeImmutable`: https://3v4l.org/oRehh

Comment: There is no need to create another reference to the `DateTime` object. `modify()` returns the `DateTime` object itself. So `$start` and `$datetime` simply point to the same `DateTime` object.

Comment: Yes that's correct, my original example should have used `DateTimeImmutable` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So in the first block, it should be `$start = new DateTime('2018-10-23 00:00:00');` right?

Comment: Any advantages of `modify` over `add` as shown by @ron-dobley ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they're pretty similar. It'll be preference of how the code looks compared to performance.

Comment: Thanks to everyone!!